# C++: what does statement 'TYPE& name(&TYPE);' mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, copy-constructor

Since I'm not very familiar with c++ new features, this`SensorManager& mgr(SensorManager::getInstance());` statement confused me a lot, I thought this is kind of variable statement or something but not sure. I believe this `mgr` is not a function because the following statement`sp<SensorEventQueue> queue(mgr.createEventQueue());`use `mgr` as an object.

`SensorManager::getInstance()`return a reference of a SensorManager type instance, but there's no constructors in SensorManager class to recieve a reference.

To my acknowledge, this statement do a action like `SensorManager& mgr = SensorManager::getInstance();`, but what on earth is this statement `TYPE& name(&TYPE)` mean? Is this a new feature of copy construct to fit with singleton pattern?

Comment: It depends. `SensorManager& mgr(SensorManager::getInstance());` Uses the copy constructor, but `SensorManager& mgr = SensorManager::getInstance();` uses the `operator=`, which might or might not be defined.

Comment: SensorManager is a `singleton`, meaning that there should only ever be one instance of it in existence throughout the program's life.

Comment: @RussleyShaw I know exactly what a singleton is, I just don't recognize this grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read the code you provided is that there is a static method SensorManager::getInstance() declared like this:

```
class SensorManager
{
    // ....
    public:
        static SensorManager& getInstance();

    // ....
}
```

and that this returns a reference to a singleton instance of a SensorManager. This reference is then used to create the reference variable mgr.

So yes the line:

```
SensorManager& mgr(SensorManager::getInstance());
```

is equivalent to

```
SensorManager& mgr = SensorManager::getInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, what I cared more is that is the former line a new c++ grammar or something?

Answer (score 0):

`SensorManager& mgr(SensorManager::getInstance());` -> this is a function declaration in following format:

> return type    function_name(parameter to function);

Function `mgr` receives an instance of type `SensorManager` and returns the  reference of an instance of `sensorManager`

Comment: I believe mgr is not a function, cause function parameter declaration will be a type not a instance. Maybe the information I offered is less, I'v add more details.